# How do I get the location (lat/lng) of a picture taken or a picture already taken

Tags: ios, objective-c

This may seem like a duplicate but the Assets Library framework (the current framework most answers are using for the same question) is deprecated as of iOS 9.0 as shown by apples developer docs.

What I need to be able to do is get the lat/lng from a photo which is either currently being taken or a photo which has previously been taken (on a iOS 5+ device as it has location tagging). Some sample code would be great

Thanks

Comment: This could help you https://gist.github.com/sumitlni/6421aece205ebefa647abe701d2429e0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
NSData* pngData =  UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 1.0);

CGImageSourceRef mySourceRef = CGImageSourceCreateWithData((CFDataRef)pngData, NULL);

if (mySourceRef != NULL)
{
    NSDictionary *myMetadata = (__bridge NSDictionary *)CGImageSourceCopyPropertiesAtIndex(mySourceRef,0,NULL);
    NSDictionary *GPSDictionary = [myMetadata objectForKey:(NSString *)kCGImagePropertyGPSDictionary];

    NSLog([GPSDictionary valueForKey:(NSString*)kCGImagePropertyGPSLongitude]);
    NSLog([GPSDictionary valueForKey:(NSString*)kCGImagePropertyGPSLatitude]);

}
```

Comment: Thanks alot, will try now and let you know!

Comment: Did you got the solution?

Comment: The problem I keep getting with this solution is that the GPS Dictionary is nill even when the image data id 385052 bytes.

Comment: You will get values in GPS Dictionary only when the image metadata have the information of it. otherwise you will get nil.